# Using submodeld in ArcGIS ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, esri-geodatabase, iteration

I have three geodatabases (176 files each) with raster data. let's call the first one as G, the second one as D and the third one as S. Now I want to perform a raster calculation so that the G1-D1-S1.... then G2-D2-S2 and so on

I think I would need two submodels (one submodel that will iterate through D files, and the other one which will iterate through S files) and one main model which will iterate through G files and then perform the calculations and then save the results in a new geodatabase .

The problem is I don't know how to do that.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looping across multiple workspaces is complex and difficult to implement in modelbuilder. If you want to work in model builder I think a simpler solution is to iterate over your numbers 1 to 176 using a [For iterator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/for.htm). This generates a number which you can use in 3 model only [calculate value](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/calculate-value.htm) tools to construct full path names to you G, D and S rasters. Then using inline variable substitution you can [Make raster layers](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-raster-layer.htm) and use those in your downstream processing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer can you please illustrate how can I do that?